# Git - stop ignoring asset but keep it in previous commits

Tags: git, gitignore

1. Let's assume I have a project under version control with `folderA` in gitignore list.
2. At some point I changed my mind and would like to track the `folderA` from now on so I remove it from `.gitignore` and add it to the source control.
3. Now when I go back in time and checkout any commit before `folderA` was checked in the folder is removed.

This sort of makes sense because as far as I get it Git has recorded adding the `folderA` from nonexistence and it ignored it earlier so it simply 'replays' the addition back in time, i.e. it removes the folder.

My question is: is it possible that starting at step 1 (or maybe even 2) above I add `folderA` to source control AND when I checkout any earlier commit (where it was still ignored) have it NOT removed? (As in *Git makes no assumptions about the folder (non)existence before being added*).

Comment: You could always checkout the file(s) from one of the later commits.

Comment: Do you mean: 1. checkout earlier commit, 2. selectively checkout files from later commit to put them back in the working copy?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was suggesting.  Not ideal, but if it works then maybe consider it.

Comment: If the files are tracked now, but weren't in an older commit, checking out back and forth between the two commits will add and remove the files as necessary, you cannot override this.

Comment: Oh, the woes of time travel...

Answer (score 0):

as long as you are happy for the first commit to have the today's version of the folder, you can do it like this.

```
git status # make sure you have no local changes
git tag pre-rebase # just in case this all goes wrong
git rebase -i HEAD~20 # or however many commits you have to go back to get to the one where you first ignored folderA.
# in the editor that comes up
# (if you don't know how to use vi, switch your default editor to nano
# before you start this process) 
# find the commit where you added the git ignore and replace pick at the start of the line to `e` for edit
# save the file and wait for the rebase to start
# when it stops, open `git gui &` click the amend radio button
# (if you don't use git gui, do it with whichever tool you use)
# remove the entry from .gitignore
# stage the changes (the change to gitignore and everythign in folder a)
# press the commit button
git rebase --continue
```

if you are lucky, the rebase will finish, and everything will be how you wanted it in your current branch.  if you are not, you can go back to the `pre-rebase` tag and try again.  If you are unfamiliar with any of the commands in the instructions, it might be good to look it up before trying it.